# Proof that the intersection of a decreasing sequence of closed bounded nonempty sets in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is nonempty using the BW theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Let $\left(F_{n}\right)$ be a decreasing sequence [i.e., $\left.F_{1} \supseteq F_{2} \supseteq \cdots\right]$ of closed bounded nonempty sets in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. I am trying to show that $F=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n}$ is nonempty. Is the following correct?

Construct a sequence, $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, by choosing a point in each of $F_{1}, F_{2},...$ etc. Since each set $F_{i}$ is bounded, there exists $M>0$ s.t. $||a_{n}||_{2} \leq M$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, by the BW theorem, $\{a_n{}\}$ has a convergent subsequence, $\{a_{n_k{}}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ $\rightarrow l$.

Clearly, $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is wholly contained in $F_{1}$. By the closedness of $F_{1}$, $l\in F_1$ Now, consider the subsequence of $\{a_{n_k}\}$, $\{a_{n_{k_{j}}}\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$, which is such that $a_{n_{k_{1}}}\in F_{i}$ for $i\geq 2$. Then, $\{a_{n_{k_{j}}}\}$ is wholly contained in $F_2$. Also, because it is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$, it too converges to $l$. By the closedness of $F_2$, $l \in F_2$.

Following a similar construction for each of $\{F_{3},.....\}$, we conclude that $l \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n}$.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. BTW, without induction, for any $m,$ the sequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{n_k\ge m}$ converges to $l$ and all of its terms are in $F_m.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since each set  is bounded, there exists $M > 0$ s.t....

The point is that $F_1$ is bounded and the sets are nested.

I think you've overcomplicated the main part of the argument. You've chosen the sequence so that $a_j \in F_j$ I assume. Since the sets are nested, you therefore already know that for any $J$, we have $a_j \in F_J$ for $j \geq J$.

Now, just working with the subsequence given by $\{n_k\}$, you know that there is some $K \geq 1$ for which $n_k \geq J$ for every $k \geq K$. i.e. the subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ eventually stays in the set $F_J$. There is no need for a 'diagonalization' style argument of picking further subsequences.